# Lpsolve for php Help installing

Tags: php, lpsolve

I am new here and I really need your help. 
I am trying to use lpsolve and I would like some help. I followed the steps in the documentation. I also have read everything here that is said about lpsolve for PHP.

Comment: Please post the code you have so far.

Comment: The thing is that at this moment i do not have use any code that is related with lpsolve, because i do not know how to make lpsolve working.

Comment: At first i followed the installation steps, here in this documentation http://web.mit.edu/lpsolve/doc/PHP.htm . The php_phplpsolve55.dll i found it in "lp_solve_5.5.2.0_PHP_exe_win32.zip" from http://sourceforge.net/projects/lpsolve/files/lpsolve/5.5.2.0/ and i put it in C:\xampp\php\ext where all the dlls are located. In the php.ini i change the extension_dir="C:\xamppp\php\ext\" and added extension=php_phplpsolve55.dll. When i try to do a test this error is showing "Call to undefined function lpsolve() in Command line code on line ...".